# ng-model doesn't bind properties, but it binds objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am very new to AngularJS and javascript in general. I was trying to create a very small app that lets add a User name and an Age, then shows the list of current users added, and their ages, here is some code I've wrote:

```js
var main = angular.module("main",[]);
main.controller("AccountController",function(){
  this.name = "";
  this.age = ""
  this.userList = [];
  
  this.addUser = function (){
    this.userList.push({name : this.name,age : this.age});
    
  };
});
```

```html
<body ng-app = "main" ng-controller = "AccountController as p" >
  <input type = "text" placeholder = "name" ng-model = "p.name" />  
  <input type ="number" value = 25 ng-model = "p.age"/>
  <button ng-click = "p.addUser()"> add </button>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat = "person in p.userList">{{person.name + ", " + person.age +" old ."}}</li>
      
  </ul>
  </body>
```

This code works perfectly, but this one doesn't:

```js
var main = angular.module("main",[]);
main.controller("AccountController",function(){
  this.user = {name : "",age : 0}
  this.userList = [];
  
  this.addUser = function (){
    this.userList.push(this.user);
    
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app = "main" ng-controller = "AccountController as p">
<input type = "text" placeholder = "name" ng-model = "p.user.name" />  
  <input type ="number" value = 16 ng-model = "p.user.age"/>
  <button ng-click = "p.addUser()"> add </button>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat = "person in p.userList">{{person.name + ", " + person.age +" old ."}}</li>
      
  </ul>
</body>
```

As you can see and test it, this code doesn't work like the 1st one, it changes automatically object's properties, but the first one doesn't change, it creates a new object and doesn't bind change object to the last object.

My problem is that I can't understand why they don't work the same way, since it's basically coded in the same way. I mean what's the **difference between the two codes**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first example you are creating **new** object. In the second example you are adding a **reference** to the object.

To make both examples behave in the same way you can write:

```
this.userList.push(angular.copy(this.user));
```

`angular.copy` creates a deep copy of an object.

Comment: Oh, alright, I totally missed that point, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
this.userList.push({name : this.user.name,age : this.user.age});
```

I think that in the second case, you push the object itself, and not only the values contained into the object.